# Vectorization: matrix array multiplication element wise one by one

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a matrix:

`R = [0 -1;1 0];`

```
array = 1:1:10;
```

Also `x0 = [2;1]`

How can I obtain another array in the most efficient way without loop?

```
array2 = [expm(1*R) expm(2*R) expm(3*R) .... expm(10*R)];
```

Then I want to obtain 
`array3` of dimension 2 by 10 such that:

```
array3 = [expm(1*R)*x0 expm(2*R)*x0 expm(3*R)*x0 .... expm(10*R)*x0];
```

Comment: `R` is a vector or matrix? It does not make sense, your `array3` could either be a 2 by 20 matrix or a 2 by 10 by 2 matrix. Please clarify.

Comment: `R` is a matrix. `array3` is 2 by 10.

Comment: As I said, it does not make any sense. `array` hast the dimension `1x10`, `R` has the dimension `2x2` the resulting matrix `array2` or `array3` can't have less than `2x2x10` = `40` elements. Please give an exact example output with numbers.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Regarding the size of `array2`, the size of `expm(1*R)` is 2x2. There are 10 such matrices horizontally concatenated in `array2` which makes its size 2x20. And regarding the size of `array3`, the size of `expm(1*R)*x0` is 2x1 and there are 10 such matrices horizontally concatenated in `array3` which makes its size in 2x10.

Comment: @SardarUsama so `expm(1*R)*x0` is supposed to be a real matrix multiplication and not elementwise? Regarding the title of the question that's not clear.

Comment: What I believe the OP means by "element wise one by one"  is: [expm(1st element of array multiplied by R)  , expm(2nd element of array multiplied by R) and so on to the last element]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know if I got your question right. Here are two solutions which are not fully vectorized, but fairly fast:

```
R = [0 -1;1 0];
A = 1:1:10;
x0 = [2;1];

%// option 1
temp = arrayfun(@(x) (expm(R*x)*x0).', A, 'uni', 0);
array3 = vertcat( temp{:} )

%// option 2
temp = accumarray( (1:numel(A)).', A(:), [], @(x) {(expm(R*x)*x0).'})
array3 = vertcat( temp{:} )
```

### Benchmark

I haven't considered [Leander's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994387/2605073) as it doesn't calculate `array3`:

```
function [t] = bench()
    R = [0 -1;1 0];
    A = 1:1:10;
    x0 = [2;1];

    % functions to compare
    fcns = {
        @() compare1(A,R,x0);
        @() compare2(A,R,x0);
        @() compare3(A,R,x0);
    };

    % timeit
    t = zeros(3,1);
    for ii = 1:100;
        t = t + cellfun(@timeit, fcns);
    end
end

function array3 = compare1(A,R,x0)  %rahnema1
    n = numel(A);
    array3 = reshape(expm(kron(diag(A),R))*repmat(x0,n,1),2,[])
end
function array3 = compare2(A,R,x0)  %thewaywewalk 1
    temp = arrayfun(@(x) (expm(R*x)*x0).', A, 'uni', 0);
    array3 = vertcat( temp{:} )
end
function array3 = compare3(A,R,x0)  %thewaywewalk 2
    temp = accumarray( (1:numel(A)).', A(:), [], @(x) {(expm(R*x)*x0).'});
    array3 = vertcat( temp{:} )
end
```

**Results:**

for `A = 1:1:10;`

```
0.1006   %// rahnema
0.2831   %// thewaywewalk arrayfun
0.3103   %// thewaywewalk accumarray
```

As `kron` gets really slow for large arrays, the benchmark results change for `A = 1:1:100;`:

```
4.0068   %// rahnema
1.8045   %// thewaywewalk arrayfun
2.4257   %// thewaywewalk accumarray
```

Answer (score 2):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential):

> If a matrix is diagonal its exponential can be obtained by exponentiating each entry on the main diagonal.

Given that a block diagonal matrix can be created from `{1*R, 2*R,...}` then its exponential can be obtained and reshaped to a `[2 * n]` and it can be multiplied by `x0`.
However its performance may be worse than for loop.

```
R = [0 -1;1 0];
array = 1:1:10;
x0 = [2;1]
n = numel(array);
result = reshape(expm(kron(spdiags(array.',0,n,n),R))*repmat(x0,n,1),2,[]);
```

For `array` of small size (less than 70 elements) full matrix is more efficient:

```
result = reshape(expm(kron(diag(array),R))*repmat(x0,n,1),2,[]);
```

Comment: you should try to substitute `kron` with `bsxfun` somehow, I assume thats the bottleneck of your solution. (See benchmark). Nice thinking though! +1

Answer (score 2):

Well I see that the matrix `R` that you have is 2x2. In case it is always 2x2, then you can use the following function ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Evaluation_by_Laurent_series)) to calculate the exponential:

```
function output = expm2d(A)
% Assuming t = 1 from Evaluation by Laurent series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Evaluation_by_Laurent_series)
s = trace(A) / 2;
q = sqrt(-det(A - s*eye(size(A))));
output = exp(s) * ((cosh(q) - s * sinh(q) / q) * eye(size(A)) + (sinh(q) * A / q));
end
```

Using the excellent comparison function provided by [thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44996667/7878502), I got the following results:

When using `expm`:

```
>> bench
ans =
    0.0181 %// rahnema
    0.1075 %// thewaywewalk arrayfun
    0.1139 %// thewaywewalk accumarray
```

When using `expm2d`:

```
>> bench
ans =
    0.0048 %// rahnema
    0.0161 %// thewaywewalk arrayfun
    0.0222 %// thewaywewalk accumarray
```

As you can see, using the function for 2d matrices leads to a 10x decrease in the runtime. Of course, this cannot be used when R is not 2x2.

Edit:
When using `expm2d` for `A = 1:100`:

```
>> bench
ans =
    0.1379 %// rahnema
    0.1415 %// thewaywewalk arrayfun
    0.1756 %// thewaywewalk accumarray
```